# Как увеличить размер input поля asp.net mvc?

Tags: html, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, mvc, view

Имеется такой блок кода во View:

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 25px">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Discription:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Event.Discription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter discription.." } })
    </div>
</div>
```

Это поле для ввода описания товара, то есть она должна быть большой.
Добавление `style='height: 100px'` приводит к увеличению окна в высоту, но текст доходя до конца не перепрыгивает вниз, а продолжает уходить за рамки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Discription:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Event.Discription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", rows="5", placeholder = "Enter discription.." } })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это помгло, спасибо, но стили бутсрапа пропали. Может знаете как поправить?

Comment: И оно по умолчанию маленькое, как увеличить его размер?

Comment: убрал стиль, добавил атрибут rows="5" чтобы увеличить размер

Comment: это не помогло..

Comment: Вот так увеличил:  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Event.Discription, 6, 40, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter discription.." } })